# Javascript onchange on select inside script

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning Javascript, and here's what I'm trying to do...

```
<body> 
<select name="selTitle" id="titles">
<option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
<option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
</select>
</body>
```

and for the script,

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 var title = document.getElementById("titles");
 title.onchange = function() {
 alert("Hi");
 }
 </script>
```

But its not working, am I doing something wrong? Here's the demo.. http://jsfiddle.net/jq9UA/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code in `onload` event:

```
window.onload = function(){
     var titles = document.getElementById("titles");
       titles.onchange = function() {
       alert("Hi");
     }
};
```

#### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jq9UA/13/)

This makes sure that select box is actually available to apply events to which you can do using `onload` event or puting your script at bottom of your page just before `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

its working fine.

just change the options like this:

[image: imagem]